# SQL | Sum up data of each day of the last 7 days with unix timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, unix-timestamp

I want to build a Chart that shows the total daily orders from the last 7 days.

```
SELECT `timestamp` AS date, SUM(`total`) AS total_sales FROM `orders`  
WHERE from_unixtime(`timestamp`) > date_sub(now(), interval 7 day) 
GROUP BY DAY(from_unixtime(`timestamp`))
```

I came up with this query, but I dont get it to display the data how I want it to be.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I use mysql, if that what you meant

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself:

```
SELECT DATE(from_unixtime(`timestamp`)) AS `date`, SUM(`total`) AS `total_sales` FROM `orders` WHERE from_unixtime(`timestamp`) > date_sub(now(), interval 7 day) GROUP BY DATE(from_unixtime(`timestamp`))
```